# Problem with adjusting the width of even pages in a two sided document wifh changepage package

Tags: packages, double-sided, fullwidth

I am using changepage package to locally control the text margins of a twosided document. 
An example of what I am actually doing is the following:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-1cm}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{adjustwidth*}
\end{document}
```

Based on the changepage documentation, the `adustwidth*` checks wether the page is odd or even and by passing a value only to the second argument the text contained within `adustwidth*`is extending into the outside margin. However it doesn't seem to work with even pages as shown below: [image: problem with adjustwidth in the even pages of a two sided document].

Can you please propose any solution?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need only some pages with different margins? I didn't understand what you want to do. Is not `geometry` package enough to you?

Comment: I need to insert at a certain point a text, which is more than 1 page long. I would like to increase the `\textwidth` of this text. 

In my document I also use the `KOMA-script`, so I wanted to avoid using the `geometry` package. The `KOMA-script` includes the command `\addmargin`, which has the same behavior as the `adjustwidth*` in `changepage` package. So I haven't managed to do it either with the `\addmargin`command